# What is the replacement of d3.scale.category10().range() in Version 4

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3 graph library v4, There is a code which using the library d3 version3 not working with version4. Particularly the function is the following

```
d3.scale.category10().range()
```

what could be the replacement for the same in version 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 v4, `d3.schemeCategory10` has to be used with an ordinal scale:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

So, to return the range:

```js
var colorRange = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10).range();
console.log(colorRange);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Besides that, there are several new colours schemes, both discrete and continuous: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

To translate the line above to D3 v4, replace it with the following:

```
d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10).range()
```

See also the [D3 v4 documentation on scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#schemeCategory10).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d3.v5

var colorRange = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```